# How to run code before controllers have been initialized

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm building a application with *Sencha Touch 2*

I want to run some code at the moment where `Controllers` have **not** been initialized yet but our app `requires` have already been loaded.

Looking at the `Ext.app.Application` source code I would really like to intercept the `onProfilesLoaded` call. But I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out on my own. Apparently you can use the `override` functionality to intercept.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.AppOverrides', {
    override: 'Ext.app.Application',

    onProfilesLoaded: function(){
        alert('Hey Mum, I just intercepted the call!');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```